# Bolt-CMS Custom taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: bolt-cms

Can a taxonomy have a hierarchy? For example, English geographic areas (counties) with towns or specialisms. Looking to see if I can create a directory with Bolt-CMS

Essex
- Chelmsford
- Colchester

Yorkshire
- York
- Doncaster

or

Programming
- PHP
- Ruby
- ASP

Hardware
- Servers
- Desktop
- Laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: no, bolt does not have hierarchical taxonomies at the moment

The longer answer: You could make several taxonomies and use the combination and maybe some smart filtering in the twig templates, it will be complicated and will break easily, but in some usecases it might work.

The hardcore programmer way: Create a custom field extension ( https://docs.bolt.cm/extensions/customfields ) that implements a multilevel hierarchy .. but that is a big job to do.